# Find the following limit: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n!e^n}{n^n}$.

Tags: real-analysis

How can I find the  limit below: 
     $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n!e^n}{n^n}$$

I tried to use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) and got

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!e^n}{n^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{{\sqrt{2n\pi}(n/e)^n‌​}}{(n/e)^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{2n\pi}=+\infty
$$

Is this right?

Comment: I suggest you use Stirling approximation for n! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: I've already used that formula, and the result can be express as follows: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!e^n}{n^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{{\sqrt{2n\pi}(n/e)^n}}{(n/e)^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{2n\pi}=+\infty.$$
Is that right?

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly right.

Comment: That you used is the kind of thing you should put on the question. I have suggested an edit to address that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$a_n =\frac{n! e^n}{n^n}$$ then $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = e \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} \geq e \Rightarrow a_{n+1} \geq e\ a_n$$ Since $a_1=e$, $a_n \geq e^n \rightarrow \infty$, when $n\rightarrow \infty$, which means $\lim\ a_n = +\infty$

EDIT: Scratch that, I made a mistake, $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \geq e \left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{-n}$$ Would someone be so kind as to downvote and/or delete this answer?

Comment: How a beautiful answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: Two upvotes and an extatic comment... :-)

Comment: @aaaaa , you can (adviced) delete your own answer.

Comment: Can't find the delete link, though

Answer (score 3):

Using Stirling's Approximaton, as $n\to\infty$:

$$n! \sim \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}\sqrt{2\pi n}$$

Therefore:

$$\frac{n!e^{n}}{n^{n}}\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}$$

Which clearly, as $\sqrt{kn}$ is monotonically increasing $\forall n>0$, blows up to infinity as $n\to\infty$, we therefore have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n! e^{n}}{n^n}=\infty$$